# Talend: from XML file to String using tXMLMap

Tags: web-services, esb, talend

I have a job with a tESBConsumer that has this method: "call(string):string".

The input string must be an entire xml file. So, I drag a tFileInputXML linked to a tXMLMap linked to tESBConsumer linked to a tLogRow.

It doesn't work! I don't know if this is correctly way or there is a easier way (like tMap) to do what I want.

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

tFileInputRaw is the component which allows you to read the raw file as a string or as bytes array or stream the file. This you can use to read your xml file and return entire file content as string

Comment: Now, I'm using tFileInputRaw linked to a tESBConsusmer. But if the tESBConsumer has an operation like "call(string):string", when the tFIleInputRaw returns a string, why I get this error in compilation "impossible convert from a string to a Document" on tESBConsumer?